# Conectar 2 microservicios

Tags: spring-boot

Tengo este metodo en para conectar con un microservicio

```
 TcpClient tcpClient = TcpClient.create().option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 5000)
            .doOnConnected(connection -> {
                connection.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
                connection.addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
            });
     private String getNombreProducto(long id) {
        WebClient client = webClientBuilder.clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient.from(tcpClient)))
                .baseUrl("http://localhost:8083/producto")
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .defaultUriVariables(Collections.singletonMap("url", "http://localhost:8083/producto"))
                .build();
        JsonNode block = client.method(HttpMethod.GET).uri("/" + id)
                .retrieve().bodyToMono(JsonNode.class).block();
        String name = block.get("nombre").asText();
        return name;
    }
```

HttpClient.from(tcpClient) esta parte del .from dice que esta deprecada como es actualmente

Comment: Versión de spring-boot?

Comment: la ultima 2.6.4